# Why is there not a way to unflag a post?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I flagged a post, but upon reflection, it should not have been flagged.  Is there a way to "un"-flag a post?  Shouldn't there be?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to un-flag a post (I suspect to avoid boy who cried wolf syndrome).

Hopefully, if you realize the post should not have been flagged, so will the moderator who comes upon the flag and handles it.

Comment: Would it be all right to flag the post again and explicitly notify the mods about the mistake?

Comment: @AndriyM Sure, but I don't see any flags currently, so I am not sure what happened with this specific flag.